# Java / Android: como exibir no Log o StackTrace

Tags: java, android, exceção, log, stack-trace

Como eu posso exibir o todo o código de erro da exceção (FullStackTrace) no Log do Android?

```java
try {
    //CODE
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG,e.getStackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Achei uma forma bem pratica, que sinceramente não sabia que podia ser feito assim.

```java
try {
    //CODE
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "Seu erro: ", e);    
}
```

Comment: Simplesmente logar a exceção e não _relança-la_ pode deixar a aplicação em um estado indefinido.

Comment: @Luiz Carvalho sua resposta foi muito útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verem que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.

Comment: Feito @iTSangar :D

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```java
try {
  //CODE
} catch (Exception e) {

  Log.e(TAG, "log de erro: ", e.getMessage());    
  Log.v(TAG, "log de verbose: ", e.getMessage());    
  Log.d(TAG, "log de debug: ", e.getMessage());    
  Log.i(TAG, "log de info: ", e.getMessage());    
  Log.w(TAG, "log de alerta: ", e.getMessage());  
}
```

ou

```java
Log.e(TAG, "log de erro: ",new RuntimeException("TAG meu erro"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso assim:

```java
Log.e("TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
```