# Exceção em eclipse Android - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, jsp

Queria fazer integração do meu projeto Android com meu Projeto Web em
 Jsp..Quando tento baixar os dados do Web para o android da esse erro:

> Fatal Exception: main  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   lenght=43; regionStart =0; regionLenght=-1

Fiz uns testes e vi que o erro está na classe RecebeJSP no método doInBackground() acionando a excessao "IOException"

> Classe RecebeJSP que recebe dados

```
 package br.com.itb.teem.agenda;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*class  OperacaoAlgumaCoisaWebServiceAsyncTask
           extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
}
* Vendo a implementação desta classe percebemos que precisamos definir alguns tipos “Generic”. 
* Para o exemplo acima, colocamos todos como Void. Vamos entender para que serve cada tipo:
* Primeiro Generic(Params)  : o tipo que pode ser enviado para a thread  background desse mecanismo, ou seja, o método doInBackground.
* Segundo  Generic(Progress): o tipo que pode ser usado para usar com finalidade de enviar o progresso de alguma execução da thread background.
* Terceiro Generic(Result)  : o tipo de retorno da thread background. */
public class RecebeJSP extends AsyncTask<Integer, Double, String> {
    private Activity ctx;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    public RecebeJSP(Activity ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    //onPreExecute() – É executado antes do doInBackground().
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Aguarde...", "Baixando dados da web!!!", true);
    }

    // doInBackground(Params…)– A thread background. É chamado quando o onPreExecute finaliza.
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             String endereco = "http://localhost:8085/projetoWeb/listaContatosOra.jsp";
            //String endereco = "http://localhost:8080/projetoWeb/listaContatosOra.jsp";
            Log.i("URL", endereco);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(endereco);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append(s.next());
                }
            }
            Log.i("Finalizou... ","Fim");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        }   
        return sb.toString();
    }

    //onPostExecute(Result)– Invocado depois que a thread principal finaliza e esta retorna algum valor como parâmetro para este método.
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String[] matrizTela= new String[5];
        String LinhaDados = null;

        //aqui ele pega a quantidade de carcteres que tem uma determinada variável  
        //e armazena numa INT para usá-la de contador  
        int contador = result.length();
        String total =result.substring(result.indexOf("{")+1,result.indexOf("}"));
        Log.i("Tot. Reg.:  ", total);
        Log.i("Tot. Car.:  ", String.valueOf(contador));
        int PosIni = 0;
        int PosFin = 0;
        String Pos1, Pos2, Pos3, Pos4, Pos5;

        //cria um for( para fazer uma varredura letra por letra até encontrar
        for(int i = 0;i<contador;i++)
        {
            //usamos substring pra pegar um caractere, passando como parâmetro,  
            //o primeiro caractere a ser pega, até a ultima.  
            //fiz um if para verificar se o caractere é igual a "?"
            if (result.substring(i,i+1).equals("?")){ 
                {
                    Log.i("i     :  ", String.valueOf(i));
                    Log.i("PosIni:  ", String.valueOf(PosIni));
                    Log.i("PosFin:  ", String.valueOf(PosFin=i));
                    LinhaDados = result.substring(PosIni,PosFin).trim();
                    LinhaDados = LinhaDados.replaceAll("[&]", " ");
                    Log.i("String:  ", LinhaDados);
                    PosIni = PosFin+1;
                    /*Caso utilize a Classe Split.java que realiza a separação dos dados
                    * Split separados;
                    * separados = new Split();
                    * matrizTela = separados.separaDados(LinhaDados, "|"); */
                    //Utilizando a metodo Split nativo do Java
                    //Exemplo nomeString.split(limit);
                    matrizTela = LinhaDados.split("[|]");
                    //Retorna cada campo em uma posicao
                    Pos1 = matrizTela[0].toString();
                    Pos2 = matrizTela[1].toString();
                    Pos3 = matrizTela[2].toString();
                    Pos4 = matrizTela[3].toString();
                    Pos5 = matrizTela[4].toString();
                    //Exibindo no console (Logcat)
                    Log.i("Pos1  :  ", Pos1);
                    Log.i("Pos2  :  ", Pos2);
                    Log.i("Pos3  :  ", Pos3);
                    Log.i("Pos4  :  ", Pos4);
                    Log.i("Pos5  :  ", Pos5);
                    //Declarando a classe de controle de conexao
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
                    // Inserting Contacts
                    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                    db.addContact( Pos2, Pos3, Pos4, Pos5);
                }           
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

> Classe Android DatabaseHandler tambem para receber dado

```
 package br.com.itb.teem.agenda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") 
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Agenda.db";
    // Agenda table name
    private static final String TABLE_AGENDA = "agenda";
    // ContAgenda Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID     = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NOME   = "nome";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL  = "email";
    private static final String KEY_FONE   = "fone";
    private static final String KEY_SEXO   = "sexo";
    // Produto table name
    private static final String TABLE_PROD = "produto";
    // Produto Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_PRO_ID    = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_PRO_DESC  = "descricao";
    private static final String KEY_PRO_CAT   = "categoria";
    private static final String KEY_PRO_VL    = "valor";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Criar Tabela agenda
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_AGENDA + " ("
                + KEY_ID    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                + KEY_NOME  + " VARCHAR(40), "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(30), "
                + KEY_FONE  + " VARCHAR(10), "
                + KEY_SEXO  + " VARCHAR(01));";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

        //Criar Tabela produto
        CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PROD + " ("
                + KEY_PRO_ID   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                + KEY_PRO_DESC + " VARCHAR(40), "
                + KEY_PRO_CAT  + " VARCHAR(20), "
                + KEY_PRO_VL   + " NUMERIC(6,2));";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);   
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AGENDA);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROD);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") // Adding new contact
    void addContact(String nome, String email, String fone, String sexo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NOME,  nome.toUpperCase());                 
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email.toLowerCase());                 
        values.put(KEY_FONE,  fone);
        values.put(KEY_SEXO,  sexo);

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_AGENDA, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connecting
    }


    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(int id, String nome, String email, String fone, String sexo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NOME,  nome.toUpperCase());                 
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email.toLowerCase());                 
        values.put(KEY_FONE,  fone);
        values.put(KEY_SEXO,  sexo.toUpperCase());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_AGENDA, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_AGENDA, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }

    // Deleting all contact
    public void deleteAllContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_AGENDA);
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {

           String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_AGENDA;
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
           int count = 0;
           try {
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 count = cursor.getCount();
              }
              return count;
           }
           finally {
              if (cursor != null) {
                 cursor.close();
              }
           }
    }


    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Agenda> getAllContacts() {

        List<Agenda> contactList = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_AGENDA;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
                agenda.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                agenda.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
                agenda.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
                agenda.setFone(cursor.getString(3));
                agenda.setSexo(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(agenda);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }


}
```

> Classe Jsp

```
<%--
    Document   : Seleciona Registros
    Created on : 10/03/2015, 17:35:37
    Author     : Alberti
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="classeConexao.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    //(" ESTOU NA PAGINA JSP - CONECTANDO NO BANCO E EXECUTANDO A SELECT...");
    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTROWEB ORDER BY NOME";
    int registros = 0;
    try{
        ResultSet dados = conexao.ponte.executeQuery(sql);
           //(" EXECUTEI A SELECT, CARREGANDO INFORMACOES NA PAGINA...");
           while(dados.next())
               {
                   out.print(dados.getInt(1));
                   out.print("|"+dados.getString(2));
                   out.print("|"+dados.getString(3));
                   out.print("|"+dados.getString(4));
                   out.print("|"+dados.getString(5)+"?");
                   registros++;
               }
        dados.close();
        } 
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    //(" INFORMANDO A QUANTIDADE DE REGISTROS INSERIDOS NA PAGINA... ")".
    out.print("#{" + registros + "}" );
    //(" TERMINEI DE CARREGAR AS INFORMACOES NA PAGINA...");
%>
```

Comment: Tem como apontar a linha específica no código? Não vi nada muito óbvio na função que você apontou da classe especificada... E também poderia adicionar o `stacktrace`?

Comment: HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

Comment: Certo, e quanto ao `stacktrace`? Tem como adicionar à pergunta?

Comment: Talvez se no lugar de capturar a exceção e só mostrar a mensagem do exceção você imprimir o `stacktrace` fique mais fácil rastrear. Acho que seria `e.printStackTrace(out);` dentro do bloco `catch`

Comment: Nao sei bem o que é stacktrace, desculpa.

Comment: Exemplo de `stacktrace`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99755/64969

Comment: Exibindo o `stacktrace` no log do console: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/616/64969

Comment: é um laranja em LogCat?

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8085 refused

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson, através  de seu comentário pude ir atrás da solução..

Answer (score 0):

> Resolvi da forma seguinte:
>
> Alterei somente o ip da classe Android RecebeJsp.
>   De "http://localhost:8080/projetoWeb/listaContatosOra.jsp"
>   Para "http://10.0.2.2:8080/projetoWeb/listaContatosOra.jsp"
>
> Na classe jsp de listagem mantive assim: http://localhost:8080/projetoWeb/listagem.jsp